# How to configure build setting in teamcity for protractor

Tags: protractor, teamcity

I have tried using commandline custom script but that's not at all helpful. 
Done like:
Tried: start webdriver-manager start [Showing "running" continously]
Tried:  webdriver-manager start [Showing not an executable command]

Answer (score 0):

You can use gulp for setting up such connection. Check out this manual:

part1: https://hamersmithblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/13/angularjs-protractor-and-teamcity/
part2: https://hamersmithblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/20/angularjs-protractor-and-teamcity-par/